# trying to run string command through system()

Tags: c++, windows, string, visual-studio-2010

How do I convert a string to something that I can execute via system()?

I have this

```
std::string out = "some command to run" + some_string_variable;
system(out);
```

This will not compile and it's giving me a conversion error

No suitable conversion function from std::string to const char *

But If I try to run

```
system("pause");
```

That works

Comment: String literals in C++ have the type `const char (&)[N]`, not `std::string`. That's why the second works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
system(out.c_str());
```

system function declared as below, which takes `const char*` as input argument:

```
int system(const char *command);
```

Comment: +1 thank you so much. I tried all sorts of things to try to convert it to a char array.

Comment: @nkuebelbeck, Please don't tell me that included `(const char *)out`. Don't ever do that.